# How do I find out my MySQL URL, host, port and username?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

I need to find my MySQL username. When I open the MySQL command line client, it only asks me for my password. I don't remember my username. And for connectivity with JDBC, I need the URL, host and port number. Where do I find all of these?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

If you're already logged into the command line client try this:

```
mysql> select user();
```

It will output something similar to this:

```
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.41 sec)
```

In my example above, I was logged in as `root` from `localhost`.

To find port number and other interesting settings use this command:

```
mysql> show variables;
```

Comment: I am getting "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist"

Answer (score 174):

If you want to know the **port number of your local host on which Mysql** is running you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the port number on which MySQL is running.

---

If you want to know the **hostname of your Mysql** you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| hostname          | Dell  |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the hostname for mysql.

---

If you want to know the **username of your Mysql** you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
select user();   


mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the username for mysql.

Comment: How can I get ip address ? I mean for above example there is 'DELL' hostname and can I get ip address instead of name ?

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist

Answer (score 33):

For example, you can try:

```
//If you want to get user, you need start query in your mysql:
SELECT user(); // output your user: root@localhost
SELECT system_user(); // --

//If you want to get port your "mysql://user:pass@hostname:port/db"
SELECT @@port; //3306 is default

//If you want hostname your db, you can execute query
SELECT @@hostname;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't know the exact variable name use `like`, as the result may contain more than 500 rows:

```
mysql> show variables like "%port%";
```

Answer (score 13):

If using MySQL Workbench, simply look in the Session tab in the Information pane located in the sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
default-username = root
password = you-know-it-better
url for localhost =  jdbc:mysql://localhost
default-port = 3306
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is probably using command *status;* In the output you'll find database, user, host and port:

```
mysql> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.13 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          43
Current database:       mysql
Current user:           user@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.13 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp852
Conn.  characterset:    cp852
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 3 hours 32 min 40 sec

Threads: 3  Questions: 197  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 214  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 190  Queries per second avg: 0.015
--------------
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use phpMyAdmin, click on `Home`, then `Variables` on the top menu. Look for the `port` setting on the page. The value it is set to is the port your MySQL server is running on.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the default settings

**default-username** is **root**
**default-password** is null/empty //mean nothing
**default-url** is **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** for apache and
**localhost/phpmyadmin** for **mysql**       // if you are using xampp/wamp/mamp
**default-port** = 3306

Comment: How URL looks like?

Comment: http://localhost/phpmyadmin in case you want to access the MySql database. And http://localhost:port/WebPageFolder in case you want to access your web page hosted on localhost

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| hostname      | karola-pc |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For Example in my case : `karola-pc` is the host name of the box where my mysql is running. And it my local PC host name.

If it is romote box than you can ping that host directly if, If you are in network with that box you should be able to ping that host.

If it `UNIX or Linux you can run "hostname" command` in terminal to check the host name.
if it is windows you can see same value in `MyComputer-> right click -> properties ->Computer Name`  you can see ( i.e System Properties)

Hope it will answer your Q.

Answer (score 1):

on local host or dedicated server, go to config.inc file inside phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

**use this:**

```
show variables where Variable_name = 'port';
```

you can check more variables by using the command (must try)

```
show variables;
```