# Cannot connect to MySQL Server database at localhost:3306

Tags: mysql, netbeans, connection

When I first set up MySQL Server in Netbeans everything worked well. Now one day I think I accidentally clicked something or my computer lost battery life when I was connected to MySQL Server, and after these event(s) I have not been able to connect to MySQL Server. I do not know for sure if either of the above events would have any effect on connecting to a MySQL Server database.

Anyway since these events I have found that I cannot "start" or "connect" to a MySQL Server databse. I am doing this all through Netbeans IDE. 
Here is a picture of how I try to connect to my databaseL:
[image]

This is what the error message says after I click connect:

Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitterdata using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver(Unknown database 'twitterdata'). The name of the database I am trying to connect to is twitterdata

1. How can I get reconnected to the MySQL Server database "twitterdata"?
2. I am not familiar with MySQL, databases, servers and I have no idea how to get reconnected. If there is any other helpful information that I should provide let me know.
3. What MySQL tools can I run to find my problem?
4. Why would the error message tell me that the database is unknown?

If I got to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data. There is a folder named twitterdata.[image]

Here are the contents of that directory:[image]

1. Please let me know if you need more information or if you have other suggestions that would help!

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try it with the password blank, just for kicks.

Comment: That allows me to connect... But I still cannot get into my database.

Comment: I just modified the question

Comment: Maybe mysqld isn't even running.  Check the list of processes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows system and  facing the error '**unable to connect localhost 3306**' at the connection time. First you have to need start MySQL services in 2 steps:

1. Press "Windows key + R" write "services.msc"
2. And run as admin start MySQL service.

Comment: Nope. This does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be three issues:

1) Either your server isn't even running. Open your command prompt and enter mysql
2)Let's say it is , can you check if it's connecting on the correct port. 
Like in the url, you are using 3306,

Try following this post:
[How do I find out my MySQL URL, host, port and username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093603/how-do-i-find-out-my-mysql-url-host-port-and-username)

3) Can you check what if there are any credentials  to the database you are connecting?

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html